# Same <div> on multiple pages

Tags: jquery, html

I have several static HTML pages containing a set of links within a `div`. Currently, when I edit this set of links, I have to make the same edit on multiple pages.

Is there an easier way to update the `div` on every page when I make a change? Perhaps I could move it to a separate HTML file and insert it using jQuery?

Comment: I can't understand what you want. But a little which my little brain understood says that you may need a database which saves links, show them and update them on edit.

Comment: use php for that; you'd lose on SEO doing that by js

Comment: Are you using anything on the server-side to generate the pages ? (php or something ?) If you really need "static" pages, you might be able to generate them offline (look at jekyll or something like that)

Comment: The correct way to achieve this effect is by using some kind of server side scripting language or SSI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Comment: Yes PHP & Database would be the solution. I don't have any php experience unsure where I would start.

Comment: Thought maybe I could use jquery and insert when page loads. That way I would only need to edit in one place.

Comment: Brett, what web server are you using? Apache, IIS? Both of those support SSI, a mechanism for grabbing a file and spitting it into place on your page. Here's [how you do it in Apache](http://www.linuxtopia.org/HowToGuides/apache_ssi.html). (Though, in the long run, knowing PHP will be more helpful to you as you get more ambitious.)

Answer (score 2):

well, what you actually need (if you want to stay with Javascript, no PHP) is templating (I can recommend you [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js))

then, your code will look like this:

```
var data = {
    links: [
    {   url: "http://",
        text: "Lorem"},
    {   url: "http://",
        text: "Ipsum"}
    ]};
var template = "<ul>{{#links}}" +
                            "<li><a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>" +
                            "{{/links}}</ul>";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
$('#DIV_CONTAINING_MENU').html(html);
```

of course, you can do the same with jQuery (and even javascript):

```
var data = [
{url: 'http://', text: 'Lorem'},
{url: 'http://', text: 'Ipsum'}
];
$ul = $('<ul></ul>');
for(var i=0,c=data.length;i<c;i++){
    $ul.append('<li><a href="'+data[i].url+'">'+data[i].text+'</a></li>');
}
$ul.appendTo($('#DIV_CONTAINING_MENU'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using PHP

```
<div>link</div>
```

save this div as separate file. and then include this file `include('filepath');` on every page. so when you want edit you just have to edit once in main file.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your links in a static file in the root folder of your website called **links.html**:

```
<div id="links">
   Your links.
</div>
```

There are a few ways you can include this file in another page; here are three of the easiest.

---

## Using jQuery

It is trivially easy using [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

**JS:**

```
$('.add-links').load('/links.html');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="add-links"></div>
```

---

## Using SSI

First, enable SSI on your server if it isn't already. (E.g. here's how you [set up SSI in Apache](http://www.linuxtopia.org/HowToGuides/apache_ssi.html), [IIS6](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/eced0b89-e052-42ff-baa8-751dd191c3b5.mspx?mfr=true) and [IIS7](http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/server-side-includes-for-html-in-iis7).) Next, add the include where it needs to be in your static file.

**HTML:**

```
<!--#include virtual="/links.html" -->
```

---

## Using PHP

Assuming PHP is correctly installed and enabled, tell the server to parse your static HTML files as PHP—e.g. by changing the extensions from `.html` to `.php`. You can include the links where they need to appear as follows:

```
<?php include('/links.html'); ?>
```